# Can you reset $pristine on a element not the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that has a grid (table rows) and each row has a `checkBox` that allows you to select that row for an action (delete, etc). There is also a select all `checkBox` that will allow you to select all the rows. When I click any `checkBox` to select a row the form is no longer `$pristine`. For my use case I don't want the form to be touched or non-pristine just because a user checked the box. I know I can reset the whole form, but what I need is to set `$pristine` on the just the control (element). I did try to set the `$pristine` in a `$timeout`, but that did not seem to work.

```
            $timeout(function () {

                // this did not work either
                scope.myForm.myelementName.$pristine = true;
                // this did not work either
                scope.myForm.myelementName.$setPristine();
            });
```

Comment: you can use $setPristine() on the check box, but that will not reset the form to pristine if all the other control on the form are pristine. I found a hack to get around it: when you click the check box I set it back to pristine, then when I cancel out of my form I  check to see if there are any other controls on that form that are not pristine. I was hoping once I set the check box back to pristine there was some method I could call to make the form check if its controls are pristine or not. I basically wrote that method myself and it manually set the form back to pristine. Dont like doing it

Comment: I should probably add that the user has the ability to edit other controls on the grid. So they may have checked the select item to delete a row and then decided not to delete, they hit cancel and they would get a warning saying "Hey you changed something are you sure you want cancel", when just selecting an item through the check box did not really change any data..

Answer (score 0):

```
function setFormPristine(form) {

            var isPristine = true;
            angular.forEach(form, function (value, key) {

                if ((typeof (value) != "undefined") && value.hasOwnProperty('$pristine') && !value.$pristine) {

                    isPristine = false;
                    return;
                }
            });

            if (isPristine) {
                form.$setPristine();
            }
}
```

Comment: This was my first attempt at it, I will refine it and unit test it. If you see something I can do better, just let me know. I am humble!